# Optimal Approach for Accessing Redux State in React App with Multiple Instances of Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a React app utilizing Redux as the state management system. In the app, I have a parent component that includes multiple instances of the same child component.

Now, I'm faced with a decision on how to efficiently access the same Redux state within all child components. I've identified two potential approaches:

**Direct Access**: Accessing the Redux state independently from each child component, resulting in multiple accesses to the state.

**Indirect Access**: Accessing the Redux state in the parent component and passing the value down to all child components to ensure the state is read only once.

Considering performance implications, what will be the more optimal approach? Are there any best practices or considerations that could help me make an informed decision in terms of performance and maintainability?

UPDATE: I know that according to the Redux documentation, it's better to go with the first approach explained above when each component requires its own data and not the same data set. However, in my particular case, I require the same data set from Redux. Would this still apply to my situation?

Answer (score 1):

[Redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store) strongly recommends direct access:

> **Connect More Components to Read Data from the Store**
>
> Prefer having more UI components subscribed to the Redux store and reading data at a more granular level. This typically leads to better UI performance, as fewer components will need to render when a given piece of state changes.
>
> For example, rather than just connecting a  component and
> reading the entire array of users, have  retrieve a list of
> all user IDs, render list items as , and
> have  be connected and extract its own user entry from
> the store.
>
> This applies for both the React-Redux connect() API and the
> useSelector() hook.

This is recommended because when you connect a parent component to provide data for children, it will result in more work when the state changes.

Comment: I agree with the statement above that each user component requires its own user entry and not the same data set. However, in my particular case, I require the exact same data set from Redux. Would this still apply to my situation?